# Recover local files with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I worked on a couple of files and checked it in. I then excluded them from the project and made a lot of changes. I then got a specific version of the project and now I can only see the files I checked in the first time. Are there any external tools or features of VS or even a temp folder to get those files back?

Comment: Where did you check it in? Are you using TFS? Github? SVN?

Comment: @Jonny TFS but I only checked it in when I originally worked on it

Comment: Why did you create a copy of your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204632/restoring-a-file-on-my-local-machine-using-visual-studio)?

Answer (score 4):

Are the files still located in your solution directory?

If the files are still in your solution directory but not showing up in your Solution Explorer you can click the button on the top of your Solution Explorer called "Show All Files". After clicking this you should be able to see all files in your solutions directory. Just right click on the file(s) you're interested in and select "Include in project".

Comment: Yes I tried that. Those files are already in the solution since I got that specific version I checked in the first time. But that is not the version I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find them on this folder:

%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio [CHANGE_VERSION]\Backup Files

Comment: Checked, nothing there

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I went to File -> Open -> In the window it allows me to open previous versions of the file. And I saw my changes there.